# Hello there this is my Trigger on Account and have to convert this code for mass usage using batch class can anyone help with that?

Tags: apex, trigger, salesforcedx, callout

```
trigger AccountTrigger001 on Account (after insert, after update) {
    if(trigger.isInsert == true && trigger.isAfter == true){
        AccountTriggerHelperClass001.accData(trigger.new);
    }
    if(trigger.isUpdate == true && trigger.isAfter == true){
        AccountTriggerHelperClass001.accData2(trigger.new);
    }
    
}


public class AccountTriggerHelperClass001 {
    
    public static void accData(List<account>AccList){
        List<id> accountIdCollection = new List<id>();
        for(account acc : AccList){
            accountIdCollection.add(acc.id);
        }
        if(System.IsBatch() == false && System.isFuture() == false){ 
            demo(accountIdCollection);
        }
    }
    @future (callout=true)
    public static void demo(List<id> accountIdCollection){
        List<account>accToUpdate = new List<account>();
        List<account>accData = new List<account>();
        accData =[SELECT id,Name,Rating,Description from account where id = :accountIdCollection];
        
        for(Account acco : accData){ 
            Http http = new Http();
            HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
            request.setEndpoint('callout:Sfdc_01/services/apexrest/Accounts/');
            request.setMethod('POST');
            request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
            request.setBody('{"accountId":"'+acco.Id+'","Name":"'+acco.Name+'","Rating":"'+acco.Rating+'","Description":"'+acco.Description+'"}');
            HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
            system.debug(response.getBody());
            system.debug(response.getStatusCode());
            
            if(response.getStatusCode() != 200) {
                System.debug('Status ' +response.getStatusCode() + ' ' + response.getStatus());
            } 
            
            else {
                System.debug(response.getBody());
                Account accObj = new Account();
                accObj.Id = acco.Id;
                string accbId =response.getBody();
                accObj.Account_Id_Org_B__c = accbId.remove('"');
                accToUpdate.add(accObj);
            }
        }
        
        update accToUpdate;
    }
    
    public static void accData2(List<account>AccList){
        List<id> accountIdCollection = new List<id>();
        for(account acc : AccList){
            accountIdCollection.add(acc.id);
        }
        if(System.IsBatch() == false && System.isFuture() == false){ 
            demo2(accountIdCollection);
        }
    }
    
    @future (callout=true)
    public static void demo2(List<id> accountIdCollection){
        List<account>accToUpdate = new List<account>();
        List<account>accData = new List<account>();
        accData =[SELECT id,Name,Rating,Description,Account_Id_Org_B__c from account where id = :accountIdCollection];
        for(Account acco : accData){
            Http http = new Http();
            HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
            request.setEndpoint('callout:Sfdc_01/services/apexrest/Accounts/');
            request.setMethod('PUT');
            request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
            request.setBody('{"accountId":"'+acco.Account_Id_Org_B__c+'","Name":"'+acco.Name+'","Rating":"'+acco.Rating+'","Description":"'+acco.Description+'"}');
            HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
            system.debug(response.getStatusCode ());
            
            if(response.getStatusCode() != 200) {
                System.debug('Exception status ' +response.getStatusCode() + ' ' + response.getStatus());
            } else {
                System.debug(response.getBody());
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's only a few changes you have to make to make this both available for batch and as a trigger.

---

First, we will make the trigger stop if it's a batch or future method:

```
trigger AccountTrigger001 on Account (after insert, after update) { 
    if(System.isBatch() || System.isFuture()) {
        return;
    }
    if(trigger.isInsert == true && trigger.isAfter == true){ 
        AccountTriggerHelperClass001.accData(trigger.new); 
    } 
    if(trigger.isUpdate == true && trigger.isAfter == true){ 
        AccountTriggerHelperClass001.accData2(trigger.new); 
    }
}
```

Next, we will make `accData` and accData2 future methods, and make the `demo` and `demo2` methods *not* future methods:

```
@future (callout=true)
public static void accData(List<account> AccList){
    List<id> accountIdCollection = new List<Id>(new Map<Id, Account>(AccList).keySet());
    demo(accountIdCollection);
}
public static void demo(List<id> accountIdCollection){
  // Rest of logic here
}
@future (callout=true)
public static void accData2(List<account>AccList){
    List<id> accountIdCollection = new List<Id>(new Map<Id, Account>(AccList).keySet());
    demo2(accountIdCollection);
}
public static void demo2(List<id> accountIdCollection){
  // Rest of logic here
}
```

---

Finally, we can create a batchable to be called:

```
public class AccountBatch1 implements Database.Batchable<Account> {
  public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
    return Database.getQueryLocator([
      SELECT Id FROM Account
    ]);
  }
  public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, Account[] scope) {
    List<Id> accountIdCollection = new List<Id>(new Map<Id, Account>(scope).keySet());
    AccountTriggerHelperClass001.demo2(accountIdCollection);
  }
}
```

---

## Notes

You should consider consolidating these two methods into a single method; you can pass in a string parameter for the HTTP method instead of calling otherwise duplicated code.

You should use `JSON.serialize` to build your JSON body; your current code may break if the account name contains some characters, such as `"`.

```
request.setBody(JSON.stringify(acco));
```

Or:

```
request.setBody(JSON.stringify(
  new Map<String, Object> {
    'accountId' => acco.Id, 
    'Name' => acco.Name,
    'Rating' => acco.Rating,
    'Description' => acc.Description
  }
));
```

You should consider using the REST API rather than a custom Apex class for the REST API call. You can use the [Tree API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.api_rest.meta/api_rest/requests_composite_sobject_tree.htm), [Batch API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_batch.htm), or the [sObject Collection](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_sobjects_collections.htm) API calls to reduce the number of API calls you need to send and receive, which will improve your code's performance and reduce API usage in the other org.

Your current code actually may hit governor limits on high volume data loads, so you should consider this a priority.

Finally, have you seen [Salesforce to Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&type=5&id=business_network_intro.htm)? This is a no-code solution you might be able to use to synchronize your account data without any code at all.